# Setting a global variable inside a JS onload() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to store the length of a Json array as a global variable to make my code more modular. I am trying to set the global variable inside the .onload function but it won't allow this. I have tried with a globalTest variable.

```
var objectLength = 0;
var globalTest = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    establishConnection();
});


function establishConnection() {
    xttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xttp.open("GET", "http://exampleServerPath", true);
    xttp.send("null");

    xttp.onload = function() {
        var Json = JSON.parse(this.response);
        objectLength = Json.length;
        globalTest = 2; // this doesn't work         
    };

    globalTest = 4; //this works
}
```

I am fairly new to JS any help is appreciated!

Comment: It *does* work, just not when you think it does.

Comment: I have this question too, and the proposed duplicate does not have a solution to my scenario, and the point of the question is different...I'd say it's not a duplicate and needs a clear (specific) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with the `xttp.onload` part. Change that to `xttp.onreadystatechange` and then check the readystate.

Check out this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

EDIT:
Your code works as expected, but maybe you think `globalTest` is not being updated.

If you were to call `establishConnection()` and then immediately try to access `globalTest` it will still be 0 because the AJAX request has not completed yet.

If you did

```
establishConnection();
setTimeout(function() {
    alert(globalTest);
}, 2000);
```

Then you should see the value you expect (assuming your ajax request completes in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: I can confirm that this has no bearing to it as I had it with .onreadystatechange before